# sugestions with Python 3 scrip

Tags: python-3.x

hello everyone I am trying to write the scrip of the question below on python , this is my second week of the class I am so lost I would appreciated any help thank you.

A member of the state legislature wants you to write a program that will calculate the cost of removing pollutants from smokestack emission for a utility company. The amount of pollutants removed is given as a percentage. The user of the program will input the percentage of pollutants to be removed. The program should output the cost of removal. The general formula is:

C=80000(p)/100-p    where p is the percentage in whole number (i.e. 50% is inputted as 50)
C equals cost

```
print("Hello Hello Guest!")
p = float( input( "Please enter the amount of pollutants removed as a Percentage Thank you.."))

C =(80000(p)/ 100-p)
print("C")
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate and print `c`:

```
c = 80000 * p / (100 - p)
print(c)
```